# mysql converting various date formats into a unified one

Tags: mysql, sql

i have come across a mysql database which has  dates entered in a varchar column in various random formats e.g below

```
01/01/1977
05-05-1980
58   ( age to be converted to date )
1.2.1990
02/02/87
01-Mar-73
```

How do i convert this into one unified format - dd/mm/yyyy

Also when i try to convert varchar into date column with this data

```
SELECT
    CAST(date_column AS DATE)
    FROM
    table_name
```

i don't know why is it giving me all nulls for date value as a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regex to check for the format, then use the appropriate specifiers in STR_TO_DATE to get a standard format. Perhaps someone can help on the regex?

Pseudo-code:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN date REGEXP '[m-d-y]'
          THEN STR_TO_DATE(date, %)
```

Specifiers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Updated: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93eb2/34.  Obviously cannot work if there are any ambiguities, i.e., some dates are stored m/d/y and some are stored d/m/y.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the `CAST()` function is:

```
CAST(character_string AS character_data_type CHARACTER SET charset_name)
```

Did you query it in the right way?